# Using StringToWordVector instead of java regular expression

Tags: java, weka, arabic, preprocessor

I'm trying to preprocess Arabic tweets using java by WEKA. And I want to remove all English letters, emoticons, and non-characters and keep only the Arabic letters by using StringToWordVector. Although I know it can be done by java regular expression, but  I'm sticking to use StringToWordVector in order to apply the preprocessing to the training data set which is from type "instances".

Please, help!

Comment: What is the problem if you remove them first with regular expressions and then apply the StringToWordVector filter?

Comment: because I want to preprocess my training set which is from type "instances" and if I want to use the regular expressions I think I should apply it on string data type. I don't know how to transform from the "instances" data type and "string" data type. If I'm wrong plz help me to get the correct answer.

Comment: You can preprocess the text in your csv or arff file first, by removing all the english words you don't need. Then you can create instances from the preprocessed  csv or arff file.